# Subtract CGRect from CGRect -- largest piece of one not containing the other

Tags: objective-c, geometry, core-graphics, cgrect

How I can substract one `CGRect` from another? I want the result `R1 - R2` to be the largest subrectangle of R1 that does not intersect R2.

**Example 1**:

```
+----------------------------------+
| +--------+                       |
| |   R2   |                       |
| |        |                       |
| +--------+      R1               |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

R3 = CGRectSubstract(R2,R1);

```
            +----------------------+
            |                      |
            |                      |
            |                      |
            |          R3          |
            |                      |
            |                      |
            |                      |
            +----------------------+
```

**Example 2**:

```
+-----------------------+----------+
|                       |          |
|                       |    R2    |
|                       |          |
|                 R1    +----------+
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

R3 = CGRectSubstract(R2,R1);

```
+-----------------------+
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|          R3           |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
```

**Example 3**:

```
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                 R1               |
|         +---------+              |
|         |         |              |
|         |   R2    |              |
+---------+---------+--------------+
```

R3 = CGRectSubstract(R2,R1);

```
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
|                                  |
|              R3                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: What would it mean to subtract a rectangle from another rectangle?

Comment: Check my example. R2 could be anywhere.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your definition is fairly ambiguous, what says whether the subtraction is horizontal or vertical? I recommend using a combination of CGRectIntersection and CGRectDivide, along with specifying a direction to remove ambiguity.

(not tested, or even compiled)

```
CGRect rectSubtract(CGRect r1, CGRect r2, CGRectEdge edge) {
    // Find how much r1 overlaps r2
    CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(r1, r2);

    // If they don't intersect, just return r1. No subtraction to be done
    if (CGRectIsNull(intersection)) {
        return r1;
    }

    // Figure out how much we chop off r1
    float chopAmount = (edge == CGRectMinXEdge || edge == CGRectMaxXEdge)
                       ? intersection.size.width
                       : intersection.size.height;

    CGRect r3, throwaway;
    // Chop
    CGRectDivide(r1, &throwaway, &r3, chopAmount, edge);
    return r3;
}
```

Comment: @cobbal: you rock..it's should work...i will check that..finally i got and that i want since last five days...:)

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect2.size.width - rect1.size.width, rect2.size.height - rect1.size.height);
```

In response to your illustration, this code I've given you here will do exactly what you want (assuming you don't care about the origin XY coordinates). I've looked through the [docs for CGGeometry functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html), and there doesn't seem to be a `CGRectDifference` or other such method defined. There is, however, `CGRectUnion`, but that does the opposite of what you are looking for.

Comment: I already check the CGGeometry functions. We have GRectUnion and CGRectIntersection. But it's not what I need.

Comment: Yeah, that was my conclusion as well. Just use the code I gave you to make your new rect and it should do what you need, again assuming you don't care about the origin coordinates. You could even name it CGRectDifference! =)

Comment: I need the right coordinates and right size for R3. I guess your example is not correct for what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Would probably go something like this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
float aWidth  = frame.size.width; /* say for instance 320 */
float aHeight = frame.size.height; /* say for instance 480 */

int final = aWidth - aHeight;
NSLog(@"Should be -160, your answer: %i",final);
```

Comment: `frame.size.height` and `frame.size.width` is a `CGFloat`, not a `CGRect`. Typo, perhaps? Also, why are you subtracting width from height? Not sure what you're doing here...

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo, its just an example.